# Shell SH : how to find if a string is present in a variable with egrep?

Tags: shell, grep, sh

For a small script shell sh

I would like to know if "of" or "the" or "is" is present in the variable Toto

```
Toto="Planet of the world"
Test= $(egrep -c '(of|the|is)' "$Toto")
if $Test > 0; then echo "OK"; else echo "NO"
```

But this code does not work ....

Somebody could help me ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Toto="Planet of the world"

Test=$(echo $Toto | grep -c "of\|the\|is")
if [[ $Test -gt 0 ]]
then
  echo "OK";
else
  echo "NO";
fi
```

Shorter :

```
Toto="Planet of the world"

Test=$(echo $Toto | grep -c "of\|the\|is")
[[ $Test -gt 0 ]] && echo "OK" || echo "NO";
```

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSS !! Thank's a lot no error and work perfect

Comment: it would be great if u could give an upvote and accept the answer :-)

Comment: You should change from old and outdated back-tics and use parentheses like this: `Test=$(echo $Toto | grep -c "of\|the\|is")`.  Also use double brackets to speed up code `if [[ $Test -gt 0 ]]`

Comment: Your welcome.  For this small test you could change your if test to :`[[ $Test -gt 0 ]] && echo "OK" || echo "NO"`

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for the precious help

Answer (score 0):

Try with a pipeline, like this:

```
 $ Toto="Planet of the world"
 $ test="$Toto | egrep '(of|the|is)'"
 $ if [ "$test" > 0 ] ; then echo 'OK'; else echo 'NO'; fi
```

Comment: Thank's a lot but I have the following error message
titi.sh line 1: $: not found
titi.sh line 2: $: not found
titi.sh line 3: $: not found